# How do I find out who in my organization created a "New" Google Site?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-sites

My company uses G Suite (a.k.a Google Apps for Business), and we have a number of Google Sites set up. Lately (as of Jan 2017), Google has released [a new version of Google Sites](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7176163?hl=en&ref_topic=6399204), but sites created with the *"old"* Google Sites are not automatically updated.

Someone in my organization has created a *"new"* Google Site, and published it to `https://sites.google.com/[mydomain.com]/[sitename]`. The site is mostly empty, and has probably only been a playground to experiment with the new features. It can probably be deleted without anyone missing it.

Now I have been assigned the task of creating a new site, and told that it should be published at the same URL, `https://sites.google.com/[mydomain.com]/[sitename]`.
In order to do that, I need to delete the existing site at that address. But no-one in my organization remembers having created the site, and no-one seems to have access to delete it.

The *"old"* sites has a *Recent activity* link in the footer, but there's no such link on *"new"* sites.

How can I find out who in my organization created the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a New Site is generated, a file is created and stored in the user's Drive account. Unfortunately, New Site creations are not logged in the Drive audit report.

Your Admin may be able to search for the owner of the file using [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/GoogleDriveManagement) to systematically scan through each user's Drive account to find the New Site file.

GAM Example: `gam user *user@domain.com* show filelist`

GAM Example Result: `user@domain.com,New Site Filename,https://sites.google.com/s/*file_id*`

If your Admin does not want to go this route, your Admin would need to file a case with Google to find the owner.

Comment: That seems to be the only possibility, and it's certainly worth a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Admin can use the method mentioned here:
[https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2018/05/see-sites-owner-and-request-edit-access.html#:~:text=When%20browsing%20a%20site%20in,the%20site%20was%20last%20published](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2018/05/see-sites-owner-and-request-edit-access.html#:%7E:text=When%20browsing%20a%20site%20in,the%20site%20was%20last%20published)

- Mike

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @user976321, please don't post link-only answers.  It is great to include links to provide additional resources or substantiate your answer however  if you want to answer a question, please include the info required in the answer itself.